# Multiple following-sibling or preceding-sibling in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Pop quiz! I have a table with multiple rows and with no unique identifiers. The only way to identify a unique row is to match more than TWO values (1 `following-sibling` and 1 `preceding-sibling` won't work). Below is a sample

```
<tr>
    <td>Map</td>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>A01</td>
    <td><a href='test0'>Test 0</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Map</td>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Tenth</td>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>A03</td>
    <td><a href='test1'>Test 1</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Map</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Fifth</td>
    <td>Forth</td>
    <td>A02</td>
    <td><a href='test2'>Test 2</a></td>
</tr>
```

I need `Test 2` and I have the below data with me.

`td[1]` which is `Map`

`td[2]` which is `Second`

`td[3]` which is `Fifth`

`td[4]` which is `Forth`

`td[5]` which is `A02`

This is the XPath that I tried:

```
//td/a[contains(., 'Test 2')][preceding-sibling::td[1][contains(., 'Map')] and td[2][contains(., 'Second')] and td[3][contains(., 'Fifth')] and td[4][contains(., 'Forth')] and td[5][contains(., 'A02')]]
```

I am getting mad in finding a solution for this!! Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: He said he tried getting mad.

Comment: Weird approach to solve current issue

Comment: Tried this, but didn't work! 
`//td/a[contains(., 'Test 2')][preceding-sibling::td[1][contains(., 'Map')] and td[2][contains(., 'Second')] and td[3][contains(., 'Fifth')] and td[4][contains(., 'Forth')] and td[5][contains(., 'A02')]]`

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier if you put the predicate on `tr`...

```
//tr[td[1]='Map' and td[2]='Second' and td[3]='Fifth' and td[4]='Forth' and td[5]='A02']/td[6]/a
```

or

```
//tr[td[1]='Map'][td[2]='Second'][td[3]='Fifth'][td[4]='Forth'][td[5]='A02']/td[6]/a
```

The reason your original attempt didn't work is because the context is `a` and `a` doesn't have any preceding-siblings at all. You would need to do `../preceding-sibling::td`...

```
//a[../preceding-sibling::td[5]='Map' and ../preceding-sibling::td[4]='Second' and ../preceding-sibling::td[3]='Fifth' and ../preceding-sibling::td[2]='Forth' and ../preceding-sibling::td[1]='A02']
```

Also note that the positions are backwards when using preceding-sibling.

Comment: This answer is similar to mine, but //tr[td='text1']...[td='textN'] is shorter patter that i used =) well done

Comment: @VitaliyMoskalyuk- Thanks. The multiple predicate version is shorter than using "and" in a single predicate. I've added that version too. Also, I only included the positional predicates because they were included in the original question so I assumed they were important.

Answer (score 1):

to get element that contains some child element:

```
tag[./child]
```

to get element that has child with some attribute that meets condition like: `[@id='someId']` or `[contains(text(),'some text')]`:

```
tag[./child[condition]]
```

to get element by several conditions:

```
tag[condition1][condition2]
```

Let's collect this into 1 locator. So to get element that contains child with text:

```
//tr[./td[text()='Map']]
```

so the pattern to repeat is: `[./td[text()='text']]`

let's add some other required children:

```
//tr[./td[text()='Map']][./td[text()='Second']][./td[text()='Fifth']]
```

you can easily create, let's say, java method for this that will get just inner text as params and will build full path:

```
 public static String getPath(String... innerText) {
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder("//tr"); //before tr  - table could be specified
        Arrays.stream(innerText).forEach(
                text -> path.append("[./td[text()='").append(text).append("']]")
        );
        return path.toString();
    }
```

So here we get tr that contains required inner text. Now we can search for `a` tag inside of it. Just add to the end of locator: `//a`
Or if you need text: `//a/text()`

**So result is:**

```
//tr[./td[text()='Map']][./td[text()='Second']][./td[text()='Fifth']]//a
```

Comment: my patter is longer than this : `//tr[td='text1']...[td='textN']`  provided by Daniel Haley, so better to us that shorted one)

Comment: I love the explanation. Thanks for saving my time. Worked like a charm!